# Field size: natural language proportion of ems ('W's or 'm's)

Tags: user-input, typography, uitextinput

This has been a dilemma for me for years, it just occurred that I should ask.

Say I have a character limit for an `input` or `textarea` I want to allow enough visible area for the user to enter the maximum amount number of characters.

Limit: 10

> iiiiiiiiii

vs.

> wwwwwwwww

Initially I would guess the size based on lorum or random text.

If you think it through: **the maximum size is based on the number of `em` sized characters in the text**.

So I went through a phase of making the minimum visible field size `em` x character limit, though obviously this is ridiculous as it's *impossible to construct a sentence made entirely of 'w's and 'm's* and textareas get stupidly big.

So my question is: what is the absolute **most** `em`-sized  characters you could possibly put in a sentence?

Or how would you go about finding this information? As a developer I put the question here, but is there a language-person-overflow that would know?

Would a woodchuck be it?:

> How much wood would a woodchuck chuck If a woodchuck would chuck wood? A woodchuck would chuck all the wood he could chuck If a woodchuck would chuck wood.

The proportion here is `14(ems)/155(chars)` -- say just under 10%.

Is there some more technical way to determine this? Is there some outlier circumstance where there would be more than this ~10% (say www.www.com)?

Hopefully with this information I can then make inputs/textareas approximately as big as they need to be: no bigger; no smaller.